# Apply `map` over property in python

Tags: python, object, dictionary, properties

I'd like to map over a property, so I tried

```
map(lambda o: cls.prop(o), list_of_objects)
```

The property is defined in an external library as:

```
@property
def prop(self):
```

However, I get a `TypeError` error.

I tested it "unmapped", and `cls.prop(an_object)` works just fine, as it should be, is equivalent to `an_object.prop`.

What am I doing wrong? How could I achieve this?

(I'm aware list comprehension `[o.prop for o in list_of_objects]`, but I want to learn and understand what went wrong above).

Comment: I strongly doubt that the unmapped access worked. You didn't have a property if it did.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A property, accessed on the class, returns the `property` object itself, and not the wrapped function. A property wraps *three* functions, the getter, setter and deleter (each of these can be `None`):

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     @property
...     def prop(self):
...         return 'bar'
...
>>> Foo.prop
<property object at 0x107102bd8>
>>> Foo.prop.fget, Foo.prop.fset, Foo.prop.fdel
(<function Foo.prop at 0x1073366a8>, None, None)
```

You need to access the `fget` attribute to get just the getter:

```
map(cls.prop.fget, list_of_objects)
```

Or, just access the attribute directly:

```
map(lambda o: o.prop, list_of_objects)
```

or use a [`operator.attrgetter()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter):

```
from operator import attrgetter

map(attrgetter('prop'), list_of_objects)
```

Using `cls.prop.fget` or an `attrgetter` have the advantage that the `map()` C loop won't have to step back into the Python interpreter loop to execute the `lambda` bytecode. Not that that matters much here, because the property getter implementation is still Python code.

Comment: `map(lambda o: o.prop, list_of_objects)` I don't know how I did not see this! I feel stupid. Will use `attrgetter`, thanks for sharing the knowledge wrt. performance!

Comment: What about `map(cls.prop.fget, list_of_objects)`, which saves an `import` statement? There is no `lambda` expression, so can the job be entirely done in C?

Comment: @AlexandreHuat: yes, that'll work. Not that it actually matters all that much, as the getter itself is still just a Python function, so the C loop still has to step back into the interpreter evaluation loop.